# Binary Tree - In Order Sorting

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

I have a quick question in a binary tree assignment. I am not sure how to fix the function to sort the binary tree in order and print it.

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method inOrder(Node) in the type BinaryTree 
     is not applicable for the arguments ()
    at BinaryTreeTester.main(BinaryTreeTester.java:21)
```

**Method Declaration**

```
// This function should sort the tree in order and print it
public void inOrder(Node current)
{
    if (current != null)
    {
        inOrder(current.left);
        System.out.println(current.data);
        inOrder(current.right);
    }
}
```

**Code**

```
BinaryTree t1 = new BinaryTree();

// Test insert functions
t1.insert(100);
t1.insert(50);
t1.insert(175);
t1.insert(200);
t1.insert(150);

// Test displayInOrder and displayPreOrder
System.out.println("InOrder: ");
t1.inOrder(); // this is the line that causes the error
```

What I understand from this error, is that since the method inOrder(Node)requires a parameter of type Node, the statement "t1.inOrder()" causes an issue since no parameter is used.

**Insert Method**

```
public void insert(int n)
    {
        // If empty -> add new element as root node
        // if root not empty -> traverse

        Node current = root; // set current to root
        Node newNode = new Node(); // create newNode 

        newNode.data = n; // set the data of newNode to n
        newNode.left = null;
        newNode.right = null;

        if(root == null)  // check if tree is empty
            root = newNode; // if yes, set root to newNode
        else
            while(true)     
                if(newNode.data > current.data)
                    if(current.right == null)
                    {
                        current.right = newNode;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        current = current.right;
                else
                    if(current.left == null)
                    {
                        current.left = newNode;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        current = current.left;
    }
```

I cannot alter the code file and can only workaround the function itself. Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: You said that `inOrder` takes one argument, a `Node` object. When you call `inOrder()` you're not passing it a node to start at!

Comment: @Purag I know I have to pass it as an argument, however, I cannot edit the tester file as instructed in the practice problem, thus I was wondering if there is a way to fix this through editing the function itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is an assignment, I won't provide code but will give some (hopefully) helpful hints.

In Java, you can declare the same method more than once as long as their signatures are different.

If the provided tester expects a zero-argument `inOrder` method to be declared, then you should just declare it!

Now, you already have a one-argument `inOrder` method that accepts a `Node` object as a parameter — this is the node to start the in-order traversal at.

How can you use this method you already have inside your new zero-argument `inOrder` to start doing an in-order traversal at the root of your tree?

Comment: this is helpful! so I guess recursion and function overloading. I will attempt to solve it again with your advice in mind thank you!

Comment: It worked Perfectly!
public void inOrder()          
 {
  inOrder(root);
 }

 public void inOrder(Node current)
 {
  if (current != null)
  {
   inOrder(current.left);
   System.out.println(current.data);
   inOrder(current.right);
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

The method signature of `inOrder` expects a `Node` *reference* to be passed as a parameter to the method, However when you invoke the `inOrder` method you're *not* passing in the required argument (a `Node` reference) which I would assume should be the root `Node`.

The solution is you'll need to pass the *reference* to the root `Node` of your `BinaryTree` as the argument to the `inOrder` method.

```
t1.inOrder(t1.root);
```

As per your comment, you want to invoke the `inOrder` method without passing in an argument of type `Node`. That's really easily, all you have to do is create another method that takes no parameters but will invoke the one which takes parameters and pass in the appropriate `Node` (root).

Comment: Thank you for sharing this :). I was hoping to know if there is another way, without passing (t1.root) as the argument? Any suggestions to changing the inOrder() function accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

The below code worked perfectly. Thanks for the guidance and sharing concepts.

```
public void inOrder()          
{
    inOrder(root);
}

public void inOrder(Node current)   
{
    if (current != null)
    {   
        inOrder(current.left);
        System.out.println(current.data);   
        inOrder(current.right);
    }
}
```